# What is cpuinfo telling me?

Tags: central-processing-unit

On my current server, when I do cat /proc/cpuinfo, I get:

E3-1230 @ 3.2ghz / 1600mhz

and there are 8 of these.

Does this mean there are 2x quad core processors?  I've looked everywhere and I'm not able to find anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The CPU has [4 Cores and 8 Threads](http://ark.intel.com/products/52271/). [cpuinfo shows you logical CPUs](http://www.richweb.com/cpu_info) so it shows you the 8 Threads of which every two share a core.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lscpu` for more useful information:

```
$ sudo lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              3990.87
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```